# Getting wrong value when multiplying

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math

I am writing an Android app and I have an algorithm to calculate some score out of several variables but when computing, I get wrong answer:

I get 10300 when I set mv, ptv, txtv to 10 whereas I should get 100. When I set it to 1, I get 300 as answer.

```
int f;
f = (((mv*ptv*txtv)/10^3)*100);
int finalScr = f;
TextView scoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
scoreView.setText(Integer.toString(finalScr));
```

All the variables are integers and the maximum value of all the variables is 10 and minimum is 1.

Please help.. I don't think I am mathematically wrong :P

Comment: As said in the answers you have to use `Math.pow()` but you can also simplify your math and just divide by 10 and not multiply by 100. Since 10^3 = 1000 and 100/1000 = 1/10.

Answer (score 12):

`^` is not the power operator in `Java`. It's an [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive-or) operator.

You should use `Math.pow(10, 3)` for that:

```
f = (int)(((mv*ptv*txtv)/Math.pow(10, 3))*100);
```

Typecast to `int` is needed, as the result of `Math.pow` is `double` type.

Comment: though your answer is correct about the problem, as long as suyash srijan uses integers, it's not the same to divide by 10 or divide by 1k and multiply after that. let mv,ptv be 10 and txtv be 49 - division by 1000 before multiplication by 10 should be 400, while division by 10 without multiplier should be 490

Answer (score 3):

^ is not the exponential operator.  Its an xor operator.  You need to make it

```
f = (((mv*ptv*txtv)/(10*10*10))*100);
```